# Почему возникает ошибка? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Взял код с этой темы: https://lolz.guru/threads/3092885/
Все вроде заработало, но когда я ввожу число сколько обьявлений надо вывести у меня выходит ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\ParserTGBot\ParserTGBot\olx.py", line 4, in <module>
    import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
```

Помогите пожалуйста!
Если что модуль установлен правильно
Устанавливал этот модуль так:
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: можете отправить установленные пакеты, бывает так что есть самостоятельный пакет telebot который конфликтует с pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, в установленных модулях есть ли **pyTelegramBotAPI** через:

```
pip list
```

2. Если в списке установленных модулей есть **telebot** - удалить.:

```
pip uninstall telebot
```

Должен остаться только pyTelegramBotAPI

3. Установить **pyTelegramBotAPI**:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'` говорит об отсутствии данного модуля. Скорее всего у вас на устройстве много интерпретаторов **python** разных версий и вы установили библиотеку не на тот. Советую вам, если вы работаете в PyCharm, скачать модуль через из утилиты.